# Receive data from CSV file as variable to "PATH" -> "HTTP Request" sampler

Tags: jmeter, httprequest

I have static domain name (test.com) of site and CSV file with path to different pages like home.html, contacts.html, projects.html and other. How I have to configure Jmeter to receive data from file as variable to "PATH" to "HTTP Request" sampler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to your Test Plan and configure it as follows:

   - Filename: `/path/to/your/csv/file`
   - Variable Names: anything meaningful, i.e. `path`

     [image: JMeter CSV Data Set Config]
2. In the [HTTP Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) define "Path" element as `/${path}`

   [image: JMeter CSV Pathh]

See [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) article for more detailed explanation of above and other settings.

---

If your CSV file structure is as simple as "one line - one entry" you can even get rid of the CSV Data Set Config and use [__StringFromFile() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) instead.

[image: JMeter String From File]